# Django F-object works wrong?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

I have Django-model

```
class QuestDocument(Model):
    document = models.ForeignKey(Document, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    quest = models.ForeignKey(Quest, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    is_actual = models.BooleanField()
```

And I try update `is_actual` field according to condition *"if `document_id` in `doc_ids` then `is_actual` should be True, else - False"*.
I tried this:

```
QuestDocument.objects.filter(quest_id=q.id).update(is_actual=F('document_id') in doc_ids)
```

But got following generated SQL:

```
UPDATE "quest_document" SET "is_actual" = false WHERE "quest_document"."quest_id" = 1;
```

I expected SQL `case` using. And now don't understand why getting such SQL.

P.S. problem is solved with

```
QuestDocument.objects.filter(quest_id=q.id).update(is_actual=Case(When(document_id__in=doc_ids, then=True), default=False))
```

but now I want to understand, what is happening when I use `update(is_actual=F('document_id') in doc_ids)`

Answer (score 1):

Answer to the last one question - "but now I want to understand, what is happening when I use". It`s actually is very easy, now F('document_id') is an object

```
>>> type(F('document_id'))
<class 'django.db.models.expressions.F'>
```

So, when your write  F('document_id') in doc_ids) it`s being evaluated before sql query be constructed, and becomes either True or False.